Flutter: avoid component rebuild when navigate
Suppose we have two pages, Each page has the same component used in both pages, Why the component keeps rebuild when user navigate push to screen 2 and pop to screen 1 ?
How to stop the custom component from rebuild while navigate ?
How to use provider to accomplish this task ?
Note that data of list view comes from FutureBuilder so the list view is wrapped by future builder and it keeps firing but i'm just simplifying the example.
class CustomListView extends StatelessWidget {
 const CustomListView({super.key});

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 debugPrint('list view rebuild');

 return SizedBox(
  height: 100,
  child: ListView(
    children: const [
      Text('item 1'),
      Text('item 2'),
      Text('item 3'),
      Text('item 4'),
    ],
  ),
);
}
}

class PageOne extends StatelessWidget {
 const PageOne({super.key});

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SafeArea(
   child: Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      children: [
        TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const 
   PageTwo()));
            },
              child: const Text('Move to page 2')),
            const Hero(tag: 'list', child: CustomListView()),
          ],
       ),
     ),
   );
   }
 }


class PageTwo extends StatelessWidget {
  const PageTwo({super.key});

  @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return SafeArea(
     child: Scaffold(
      body: Column(
       children: [
        TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: const Text('Move to page 1')),
          const Hero(tag: 'list', child: CustomListView()),
        ],
      ),
     ),
   );
    }
  }


check StatelessWidget.build official docs, they say:: "The framework calls this method when this widget is inserted into the tree in a given BuildContext and when the dependencies of this widget change (e.g., an InheritedWidget referenced by this widget changes). This method can potentially be called in every frame and should not have any side effects beyond building a widget." - this means that it can be called multiple times (even every single frame) and you cannot help it

@pskink Thanks for clarification, What do you suggest ? Does using Page view fix the problem ?

but actually what is "the problem"? you are doing some "side effects" during build method?

@pskink Simply the problem is CustomListView component is a FutureBuilder, it keeps firing each time user navigate to desired screens knowing that CustomListView is used in both screens

yep, it keeps firing, whats wrong with that? are you doing any "side effects" here?

@pskink i just need to trigger it once and i don't want it to trigger back when naviagte

you cannot do that - this is how the framework works - again: StatelessWidget.build can be called even every single frame (especially when doing animations) and there is nothing wrong with it

Assign same ValueKey on both pages.

the problem with future builder, it keeps firing each time user navigate
